# Caffe, operations among batches

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network

Since I have a classifier based on single patch scores, I would like to sum together the predictions a network produces for different images.

From 
https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto, *Reduction* does not support operation over axis different than the last one.
Also a pooling operation would produce an average of its input but, obviously, without touching on the full batch.

I have implemented a python layer, but this is not fast enough for large scale experiments.

Is there a way to "sum" or, more generally, operate over the first axis with the tools already available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can. If you have `N x p x q x r` blob of prediction, the first use `Slice` ([SliceLayer](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/doxygen/classcaffe_1_1SliceLayer.html)), creating `N` blobs, each of shape `1 x p x q x r`. Then use these `N` blobs as `N` bottoms for the `eltwise` ([EltwiseLayer](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/doxygen/classcaffe_1_1EltwiseLayer.html)) layer to produce a single top.

Comment: I thought about this, but the problem in my case is that `SliceLayer` would require as many top blobs as the batches (if I am not wrong).  Since I would need 100 hundred top blobs I was trying to find other solutions.

Comment: So are you concerned that your .prototxt will become complex, or are you concerned about execution time? If its the latter (time), then you can time it, without slice layer and with. Regarding writing prototxt, I generally use a Python code to write prototxt (inspired from [this](https://github.com/XiaozhiChen/resnet-generator/blob/master/resnet_generator.py) code). That makes writing 100 top blobs really easy. Otherwise, I don't see any other method using existing layers. Of course, you can always write your own layer, which combines `Slice` and `Eltwise`.

Comment: Thank you for this complete answer. I am more concerned about time. I will give it a try and see how much does it take.

Answer (score 1):

If your predictions have the dimensions: `N x c` (for mini-batch size of `N` and `c` channels), then you can splice this into `c` blobs with dimension `N`. You can feed these into a `Reduction` layer.

For example, you to write the following as a Jinja2 template:

```
layer {
  name: "pred-slice"
  type: "Slice"
  bottom: "pred"
{%- for num in range(10) %}
  top: "pred-{{ num }}-vector"
{%- endfor %}
  slice_param {
    slice_dim: 1
{%- for num in range(1, 10) %}
    slice_point: {{ num }}
{%- endfor %}
  }
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
}

{%- for num in range(10) %}
layer {
  name: "pred-{{num}}"
  type: "Reduction"
  bottom: "pred-{{ num }}-vector"
  top: "pred-{{ num }}"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
  reduction_param {
    operation: MEAN
  }
}
{%- endfor %}
```

which expands to:

```
layer {
  name: "pred-slice"
  type: "Slice"
  bottom: "pred"
  top: "pred-0-vector"
  top: "pred-1-vector"
  top: "pred-2-vector"
  top: "pred-3-vector"
  top: "pred-4-vector"
  top: "pred-5-vector"
  top: "pred-6-vector"
  top: "pred-7-vector"
  top: "pred-8-vector"
  top: "pred-9-vector"
  slice_param {
    slice_dim: 1
    slice_point: 1
    slice_point: 2
    slice_point: 3
    slice_point: 4
    slice_point: 5
    slice_point: 6
    slice_point: 7
    slice_point: 8
    slice_point: 9
  }
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
}
layer {
  name: "pred-0"
  type: "Reduction"
  bottom: "pred-0-vector"
  top: "pred-0"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
  reduction_param {
    operation: MEAN
  }
}
layer {
  name: "pred-1"
  type: "Reduction"
  bottom: "pred-1-vector"
  top: "pred-1"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
  reduction_param {
    operation: MEAN
  }
}
layer {
  name: "pred-2"
  type: "Reduction"
  bottom: "pred-2-vector"
  top: "pred-2"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
  reduction_param {
    operation: MEAN
  }
}
layer {
  name: "pred-3"
  type: "Reduction"
  bottom: "pred-3-vector"
  top: "pred-3"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
  reduction_param {
    operation: MEAN
  }
}
layer {
  name: "pred-4"
  type: "Reduction"
  bottom: "pred-4-vector"
  top: "pred-4"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
  reduction_param {
    operation: MEAN
  }
}
layer {
  name: "pred-5"
  type: "Reduction"
  bottom: "pred-5-vector"
  top: "pred-5"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
  reduction_param {
    operation: MEAN
  }
}
layer {
  name: "pred-6"
  type: "Reduction"
  bottom: "pred-6-vector"
  top: "pred-6"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
  reduction_param {
    operation: MEAN
  }
}
layer {
  name: "pred-7"
  type: "Reduction"
  bottom: "pred-7-vector"
  top: "pred-7"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
  reduction_param {
    operation: MEAN
  }
}
layer {
  name: "pred-8"
  type: "Reduction"
  bottom: "pred-8-vector"
  top: "pred-8"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
  reduction_param {
    operation: MEAN
  }
}
layer {
  name: "pred-9"
  type: "Reduction"
  bottom: "pred-9-vector"
  top: "pred-9"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
  reduction_param {
    operation: MEAN
  }
}
```